# Foreign Key Constraint Failed Django with UUID

Tags: django, foreign-keys

Trying to save to a table with a foreign key but come up with a IntegrityError: Foreign Key Constraint failed.  I have checked to make sure I am getting the correct data for my foreign key and it seems to be there.  I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Models.py

```
class IPHold(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    CHOICES = [
        ('1', 'Book'),
        ('2', 'Documentary'),
        ('3', 'Graphic Novel/Comic'),
        ('4', 'Journalism'),
        ('5', 'Merchandise'),
        ('6', 'Podcast'),
        ('7', 'Stage Play/Musical'),
        ('8', 'Video Game'),
    ]
    media_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES, blank=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    author_creator = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    production_company = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

class RoleHold(models.Model):
    ip = models.ForeignKey(IPHold, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ip_role')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False)
    TYPE = [
        ('1', 'Lead'),
        ('2', 'Supporting'),
    ]
    role_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE, blank=True)
    age_min = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True)
    age_max = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True)
    ETHNICITY = [
        ('1', 'American Indian or Alaska Native'),
        ('2', 'Asian'),
        ('3', 'Black or African American'),
        ('4', 'Hispanic or Latino'),
        ('5', 'Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander'),
        ('6', 'White'),
        ('7', 'Unknown/Irrelevant'),
    ]
    race = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ETHNICITY, blank=True)
    GENDEROPTIONS = [
        ('1', 'Male'),
        ('2', 'Female'),
        ('3', 'N/A'),
        ('4', 'Unknown/Irrelevant'),
    ]
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDEROPTIONS, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Views.py

```
def add_characters(request):
    id = request.GET.get('id')
    ips = IPHold.objects.get(uuid=id)
    form = forms.AddCharacter
    context = {
        'form':form,
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ip = ips
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        role_type = request.POST.get('role_type')
        age_min = request.POST.get('age_min')
        age_max = request.POST.get('age_max')
        race = request.POST.get('race')
        gender = request.POST.get('gender')
        description = request.POST.get('description')
        role_save = RoleHold(ip=ip, name=name, role_type=role_type, age_min=age_min,
                        age_max=age_max, race=race, gender=gender, description=description)
        role_save.save()
        if request.POST.get('add') == 'Add Another Role':
            return redirect('/iphold/add_characters/?id=' + str(ips.uuid))
        else:
            return(render, 'iphold/pay.html')
    return render(request, 'iphold/add_characters.html', context)
```

The error I am getting is IntegrityError at /iphold/add_characters/

FOREIGN KEY constraint failed.  When I print(ip) it shows the object is there.

Comment: assume that in your id it is id (integer number), and not uuid. Try the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in your id it is id (integer number), and not uuid. Try to print the id, what it will show. You want to select by id, so you need to specify the id field and select uuid in the resulting object. Try doing the following:

```
id = request.GET.get('id')
ips = IPHold.objects.get(id=id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I was actually passing the uuid through the url and calling it id.  Ultimately I scrapped the uuid altogether and used a user_passes_test decorator to solve any potential security issues with just using the id.